# .NET 4.x Редактирование реестра при помощи C#

Tags: c#, cmd, реестр

Данная команда отказывается вносится в реестр, права администратора получены через фаил манифеста.

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectDraw").SetValue("VGABuffer", 1433331);
```

А если ввести эту команду, приложение выдает ошибку `Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Direct3D").SetValue("VGABuffer", 21181233);`

Сама ошибка:

```
System.IO.IOException: "Параметр задан неверно.
" Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов:
[Внешний код]
kicklag.Form1.button2_Click(object, System.EventArgs) в Form1.cs
[Внешний код]
kicklag.Program.Main() в Program.cs
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уточнил вопрос, посмотрите - так понятно?

Comment: Запустите приложение как x64 сборку, а не как Any CPU. И может OpenSubKey надо, а не CreateSubKey.

Comment: Так частично решило проблему, теперь первая команда выполнилась но со второй, выдает что не верно задан параметр, но если вписать через cmd то параметр задаётся, можете подсказать что сделать?

Comment: OpenSubKey тоже не помогает

Comment: Перед Wow6432Node должно быть Software.

Comment: Большое спасибо!